# What is this resistor array package type?

Tags: resistors

I looked around the Digikey and Mouser web sites and also Googled to find the exact same resistor array package, But still i couldn't find it. Can anyone tell me what is this resistor package called or help me out to find 22R in same package?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not a good photo, but you can try looking for SOT23-6 resistor arrays

Comment: Please, post decent photos!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't show any effort of posting decent photos.

Comment: If you cannot make better photos, at least measure the distance between the pins.

Comment: Sorry for the blurry image as i couldn't get around a macro lens. I have added another picture if you could get a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a SOT23-6, probably check here:
http://sg.element14.com/w/c/semiconductors-ics/digital-potentiometers/volatile-digital-potentiometers?potentiometer-ic-case-style=sot-23